# Java - Grocery list as a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a grocery list as a `JFrame` in Java. I have a `JTextField` "input" where you can put in what you want to add and the input will be saved in a `String` "eingabe", then a `JButton` "button" where you can add what you want to add.

If you press the `JButton` "button" it creates a `JLabel` "label"(with the value of the String "eingabe"), a `JCheckBox` "box" and a JButton "button2" what should be the delete button of the item.

So if you press the `JButton` "button2" it should delete the added item(JLabel "label"), the `JCheckBox` "box" and the  `JButton` "button2".

It works all fine but if i press the button2 it only deletes the last item added. What can i do to link every delete button to the associated label,box and button itself?

Maybe using a list or an array or something like that. If yes, can you explain the logic on how to  implement that?

I hope you can understand what i am trying to ask.

Here is my code:

```java
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Layer  extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    // Alle Konstruktoren,Variablen, Attribute oder so
    private JButton button,button2;
    private JTextField input;
    private JLabel label;
    private String eingabe;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JCheckBox box;
    
    
    public void Fenster() {
                
        // Wenn das X rechts oben gedrückt wird, wird das Fenster geschlossen
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        // Titel und Größe des JFrame werden gesetzt
        this.setTitle("Einkaufsliste");
        this.setSize(300,700);
        this.setResizable(false);
        
        // Neues Objekt von JTextField wird erstellt und alles wird direkt markiert und die Größe wird gesetzt 
        input = new JTextField("Hier eingeben");
        input.selectAll();
        input.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,20));
        
        
        // Neues Objekt von JTextField wird erstellt, zentral ausgerichtet und ein ActionListener hinzugefügt
        button = new JButton("Hinzufügen");
        button.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        // Neues Objekt von JPanel wird erstellt und das BoxLayout hinzugefügt 
        panel = new JPanel();
        
        panel.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(panel, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        
        // Das JTextField "input" und dem JButton "button" werden dem JPanel "panel" hinzugefügt
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
        panel.add(input);
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
        // Der soll einfach eine Trennlinie erstellen 
        panel.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
        
        
        //Dem JFrame "this" wird das JPanel "panel" hinzugefügt
        this.add(panel);
        
        // Dem JButton "button" wird ein KeyListener hinzugefügt
        button.addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);
        
    }
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            button.doClick();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Wenn button gedrückt wird passiert das
        if(e.getSource() == this.button) {
            
            
            // neues Objekt von JLabel wird erstellt und panel hinzugefügt
            label = new JLabel();
            panel.add(label);
            
            // neues Objekt von JButton wird erstellt und ActionListener hinzugefügt
            button2 = new JButton("Löschen");
            button2.addActionListener(this);
            
            // String eingabe bekommt den Wert der im TextField input drinne ist
            eingabe = input.getText();
            
            // In Label wird der Wert des Strings eingabe gegeben und zentral ausgerichtet
            label.setText(eingabe);
            label.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            
            // neues Objekt von JCheckBox wird erstellt und panel hinzugefügt
            box = new JCheckBox();
            panel.add(box);
            
            // label,box und button2 werden zentral ausgerichtet
            label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            box.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            button2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            
            // button2 wird dem Panel hinzugefügt
            panel.add(button2);
            
        }
        //Wenn button2 gedrückt wird passiert das
        if (e.getSource() == button2){          
                label.hide();
                box.hide();
                button2.hide();
            }   
        }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: A `JList` is probably what you are looking for. See [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). You can then add your items to this list to display them. The linked tutorial shows you how to add and delete items from your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue of only latest components getting deleted, is because there is a single reference of **JLabel/JButton/JCheckBox**, which gets updated when Add button is clicked.

So on deletion only these latest updated references gets cleared from UI.

Instead of adding individual elements, you can add **JLabel/JButton** to a new **JPanel** and on **Delete** button click, just check for the [Component.getParent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent--), on which click happened, as shown in this demo program.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AddDeleteFrame {
    
    private JFrame frame;
    private int counter;
    
    private void displayGUI () {
        counter = 0;
        frame = new JFrame ( "Add Delete JFrame" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        
        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel ( new GridLayout ( 0, 1, 5, 5 ) ) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
                return new Dimension ( 600, 400 );
            }
        };
        JButton button = new JButton ( "Add" );     
        button.addActionListener ( new ActionListener () {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent ae ) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
                ++counter;
                JLabel label = new JLabel ( "Counter: " + counter );
                final JButton b = new JButton ( "Delete" );
                b.addActionListener ( new ActionListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent ae ) {
                        contentPane.remove ( b.getParent () );
                        frame.revalidate ();
                        frame.repaint ();
                    }
                } );
                
                panel.add ( label );
                panel.add ( b );
                contentPane.add ( panel );
                frame.revalidate ();
                frame.repaint ();
            }
        } );
        
        contentPane.add ( button );
        
        frame.setContentPane ( contentPane );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform ( true );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }
    
    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater ( new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                new AddDeleteFrame ().displayGUI ();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```